# OpenGL simplest way to colour polygon surfaces?

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I need to fill the surface of the polygons I've just drawn with some fancy pattern (something like a blurred spiral would be enough but the pattern itself is not a problem). The shapes should remain fixed to the surface of each polygon as it rotates.

My problem is that I don't know the right way to tell the shaders to colour each point of the surface in a different way depending on their position.

P.S.: Texturing seems like overkill.

Comment: How is this not texture?

Comment: I don't know that's why I'm asking

Comment: Any good [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures) will give you the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw point by point, and put to a "uniform vec4 RGBA" into fragment shader, then use the values to output

Comment: do you mean drawing the polygons point by point? I'm supposed to draw them as a mesh of triangles!

Comment: @RobiNoob: Do you know what a fragment shader is?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:
 0-1 is max value for size of a texture;
make (1/vTextureCoords.x + 1/vTextureCoords.y )/2 and you get a number, and this one sum it gl_FragColor.xyz (not summed to alpha channel);